# How to easily change the default compiler optimization option for a project?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I am now a sophomore in university and just started learning compiler few months ago. I am wondering what tool will make it easier if I want to enable -O3 as default option instead of -O1.

Comment: Give more precision about your project's contraints (already use a build tool like CMake,...?) and you want exactly.

Comment: read about makefile

Answer (score 0):

To change the global compiler defaults for all projects, you will have to install a new spec file in the place where your GCC installation expects it (for example, `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/specs`). See [Spec Files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) in the GCC documentation.  This might work:

```
*cc1_options:
+ %{!O*:-O3}

*cc1plus_options:
+ %{!O*:-O3}
```

It enables `-O3` if no `-O` option is set.

Note that this risks breaking quite a few build systems because few of them will expect that `-O3` is enabled by default.